# DELETE query not working in sqlite in Java

Tags: java

This is my function which giving error every time I run this

```
public static void deletePreviousInvoice(int invoice_id)
{
    try {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE_NO = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            s.setInt(1, invoice_id);
            s.executeQuery();
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GENERATE_METHODS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

ERROR IS THIS autocommit is set to true my all insert query and select query are running but delete query is not working every time i run this database gets locked

---

```
Mar 25, 2017 5:04:01 PM GENERATE_INOVICE.GENERATE_METHODS deletePreviousInvoice
        SEVERE: null
        java.sql.SQLException: database locked
            at org.sqlite.DB.execute(DB.java:270)
            at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.execute(PrepStmt.java:57)
            at GENERATE_INOVICE.GENERATE_METHODS.deletePreviousInvoice(GENERATE_METHODS.java:224)
            at GENERATE_INOVICE.GENERATE_INVOICE.jButton_invoiceActionPerformed(GENERATE_INVOICE.java:815)
            at GENERATE_INOVICE.GENERATE_INVOICE.access$1100(GENERATE_INVOICE.java:27)
            at GENERATE_INOVICE.GENERATE_INVOICE$14.actionPerformed(GENERATE_INVOICE.java:659)
            at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
            at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
            at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
            at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
            at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
            at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
            at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
            at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
            at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
            at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
            at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
            at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
            at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
            at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to the answer above, the error generated:

```
java.sql.SQLException: database locked
```

Is possible due to the connection not being closed after a query you have made previously.